# MYSQl query order by count best tag match

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to sort a MYSQL query and want to show the results that has the best tag matches, show first. Tried for more than 6 hours.. Why is ORDER BY not working?

When i manually add a quote to tags "293,2376,231,8,2088,9,171,4,18,7,1,40,657,23,2339,5,96,2904,702,1936" it does comes first.. But the quote that comes second only got 4 tag matches and 10th place got 7 matches.

Databases

itemtag

```
itemid, 
tagid
```

quotes

```
id, 
bg_image, 
author, 
active
```

quotes_en

```
id, 
quote
```

```
<?php
$topictagid = "293,2376,231,8,2088,9,171,4,18,7,1,40,657,23,2339,5,96,2904,702,1936";

$sQuery = "SELECT quotes.id, bg_image, author, tagid, active, itemid, quote     
            FROM itemtag
                LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.id = itemtag.itemid
                LEFT JOIN quotes_en ON itemtag.itemid = quotes_en.id
            WHERE tagid IN (".$topictagid.") 
            AND quotes.active = 1 
            GROUP BY itemid 
            having count(tagid) > 2 
            ORDER BY count(tagid) DESC
            LIMIT 50";
?>
```

Comment: Can you echo out your query and show that? With the variables, it's hard to see what's happening with `$sortby`

Comment: @aynber

SELECT quotes.id, bg_image, author, tagid, active, itemid, quote, count(tagid) as countag FROM itemtag LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.id = itemtag.itemid LEFT JOIN quotes_en ON itemtag.itemid = quotes_en.id WHERE tagid IN (293,2376,231,8,2088,9,171,4,18,7,1,40,657,23,2339,5,96,2904,702,1936 ) AND quotes.active = 1 GROUP BY itemid having count(tagid) > 2 ORDER BY countag DESC LIMIT 50

I removed ".$sortby." since it has no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your ***ORDER BY*** work with this?

```
$topictagid = "5,10,16,17";

$sQuery = "SELECT quotes.id, bg_image, author, tagid, active, itemid, quote, count(tagid) as countag     
            FROM itemtag
                LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.id = itemtag.itemid
                LEFT JOIN quotes_".$language." ON itemtag.itemid = quotes_".$language.".id
            WHERE tagid IN (".$topictagid.") 
            AND quotes.active = 1 
            GROUP BY itemid 
            having count(tagid) > 2 
            ORDER BY countag DESC ".$sortby." 
            LIMIT 50";
```